# Getting vanityName from Sign in with linkedin for 3-legged authorization flow

Tags: javascript, oauth, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get the vanity name of the signed in user using 3-legged OpenID auth.
The linkedin documentation looks out of date. It says you have to use r_liteprofile, but
[linkedin documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin%2Fcompliance%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-unversioned&preserve-view=true#retrieve-current-members-profile) the scope doesn't match with what I see in the developer console: [image]

The only available scopes are openid, profile, and email.
When hitting https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo, the accessToken works fine and returns a JSON object with the user details. But vanityName is missing. I need this.

When hitting https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me,

I get this error:
{
"serviceErrorCode": 100,
"message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET /me",
"status": 403
}

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Support for `r_liteprofile` was dropped from version 202306 onward, but the LinkedIn API documentation has not been updated.

The minimal permissions required for access to the `/rest/me` enpoint will be `r_basicprofile` going forward.

If you still get a permission error after you use the new permission/scope, wait 5 minutes and try again, to make sure you aren't getting the error from [the LinkedIn API auth caching bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77847103/linkedin-api-access-denied-not-enough-permissions-to-access).